# Custom weekends in Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar

My workplace moves workdays to weekends, and weekends to workday: for example, Friday, March 9th is weekend but Sunday, March 11th is a workday.

How I can mark these new weekends as weekends in Google Calendar, and mark new workdays as workday?

I want to see it in my Android calendar. I want to set up all this stuff ( http://variant52.ru/kalendar/proizvodstvennui-kalendar-2012.htm, red days are actual weekends) once per year in 1 calendar and sync with other apps, and share it with people.

Comment: You're confusing weekend with days off and holidays. You just need to subscribe to a calendar feed that shows the changes as all-day events.

Comment: Additionally, you've asked 2 questions: How to change weekends in Google Calendar (web) and in Android's calendar app. Please split your Android question to a new question.

Comment: "You just need to subscribe to a calendar feed that shows the changes as all-day events." there is no such calendar

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Settings** (Cog wheel on the upper-right side of the page)
2. Search for **Week starts on:**
   [image]
3. Set it to what it suit you
4. Click on the **Save** button on top or at the bottom of the page

Comment: you missunderstand me I need to move to google calendar this calendar http://variant52.ru/kalendar/proizvodstvennui-kalendar-2012.htm

Comment: Your question was/is “How I can mark theese new weekends as weekends in google calendar, and mark new workdays as workday?” Do you want to import a calendar that has shifted weekends to Google Calendar? Is this what you are asking? Please edit your question to reflect what you are actually asking.